# Let an object be configured by another class

Tags: c#, design, object-oriented-design

I am currently planning a monitoring server for a distributed system. In a file (or maybe a database, someday) I save all the servers and parameters that I want to monitor. When the monitoring system starts, I parse that configuration file and store the content in a Configuration class (see source code below). In order to be independent from the storage type (file, database, ...) I use the IConfigurationHandler Interface (ok, I admit that the name doesn't really fit :)), whose implementations are responsible for reading/writing the file content.

I considered the following design:

```
public class Configuration
{
    private IConfigurationHandler _configHandler;

    public Configuration(IConfigurationHandler configHandler)
    {
        this._configHandler = configHandler;
        this.Load();
    }

    public void Load() 
    {
        this._configHandler.LoadConfigurationInto(this);
    }
}


public class XmlDocumentConfigurationHandler : IConfigurationHandler
{
    public void LoadConfigurationInto(Configuration configuration)
    {
        configuration.X = "...";
        configuration.Y = "...";
        configuration.Z = "...";
    }
}
```

If I wanted to use the Configuration class, the only thing I would have to do is add a dependency to the constructor (assuming that I am using a DI-Framework).

```
public class ConfigurationConsumer
{
    public ConfigurationConsumer(Configuration configuration)
    {
        // Do something with the configuration
    }
}
```

But somehow this code gives me a bad feeling. What do you guys think about it?
Is it "good" if an object let's configure itself by another class?
Even though it "feels" wrong, I cannot think of a particular case where this design has any negative impact.

Another approach would be to call the IConfigurationHandler directly from the class that needs the Configuration, as follows:

```
public class Configuration
{
    public Configuration() { }
}


public class XmlDocumentConfigurationHandler : IConfigurationHandler
{
    public Configuration GetConfiguration()
    {
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
        configuration.X = "...";
        configuration.Y = "...";
        configuration.Z = "...";
    }
}


public class ConfigurationConsumer
{
    public ConfigurationConsumer(IConfigurationHandler configurationHandler)
    {
        var configuration = configurationHandler.GetConfiguration();
        // Do something with the configuration
    }
}
```

The problem with this approach is, that I would need to accept an `IConfigurationHandler`, even though the only thing I need is a `Configuration` object.

Here is a (very) rough outline of my architecture:
[image]

And here is an example for the content of the configuration file:

```
<servers>
    <server id="1">
        <monitored_values>
            <monitored_value name="CpuUsage"/>
            <monitored_value name="..."/>
        </monitored_values>
        <!--some more configuration-->
    </server>

    <server id="...">
        <!--some more configuration-->
    </server>

    <server id="n">
        <!--some more configuration-->
    </server>
</servers>
```

The actual configuration file then would, among others, contain a list with all servers, which themselves contain a list with their monitored parameters.

Comment: If I understand correctly, each kind of monitored server has a different config and this config should be retrieved from different storage systems (file, DB, ...) ?

Comment: Actually I'm planning to have a single configuration file (, DB, ...) and a single Configuration object. The file (and the Configuration object) contains the information of each monitored server. I will update the question with a rough outline of the architecture and an example of a configuration file.

Comment: Just a hint - when a C# dev reads "Handler", we immediately think about events. Interfaces normally represent a capability of something, and thus they end up having names like "IEnumerable", "ISerializable", etc. I would suggest calling your interface "IConfigurable" or something like that.

Comment: OMG - Think about what you are trying to do and how unnecessarily complicated you made it.

Answer (score 1):

I think it gives you a "bad feeling" because it breaks **encapsulation**. When doing this:

```
configuration.X = "...";
configuration.Y = "...";
configuration.Z = "...";
```

what should be the internal state of a `Configuration` is publicly exposed.

So far I understand, something like this should be enough ?

```
public class Configuration
{
    private X x;
    private Y y;
    private Z z;

    public Configuration(X x, Y y, Z z)
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.z = z;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, I think that I did miss some details in my question. Sorry about that. See the edited answer for further information

Comment: I mean "See the edited *question*", of course. :-) The introduction has changed.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it "good" if an object let's configure itself by another class?

Yes. It's done all the time.

As @spotted said, it's encapsulation. But I want to add that this encapsulation should be realized through the concept of the "factory".

Make a factory class that has-a configuration object. Client code only tells the factory what object to make. The factory can be complex as needed to create  according to the configuration "specification".  The factory concept is meant to scale and address object structure: "factory method", "factory", and "abstract factory" reflect this scaling. "Builder" is a companion pattern addressing object creation complexity.